# When I catch the error in async/await, I encounter a problem. The statement in the try will not be executed but will directly jump to error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, async-await, try-catch

I have used `async/await` in the `handleLogin` method, and the method after await gets an error

[image]

The same problem occurs with actions in the Store
[image]

Comment: you don't need a explicit try/catch. Instead use the reject block after success in promise.

Comment: Please post code as text, not paintings.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! Also a `catch` that just rethrows the error is quite pointless

Comment: *What* error do you get when it jumps to the exception handler?